# Two $p$-groups whose automorphism groups have isomorphic Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Fix a prime $p$, and let $M$ be the unique nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$.  Let us denote by $E_n$ the elementary abelian group of rank $n$.

Is it true that $\operatorname{Aut}(M \times E_n)$ and $\operatorname{GL}(n+3,p)$ have isomorphic Sylow $p$-subgroups?

For $n=0$ they are isomorphic; and If I'm not mistaken they have the same order for all $n$.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the question, but it seems to me that $M\times E_n\cong E_{n+3}$.  Viewing $E_{n}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$, we then have the isomorphism of groups $\mathrm{Aut}(E_n)\cong\mathrm{GL}(n,p)$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Jared: thanks for your comment; You may notice that $M$ is not abelian, so that $M \times E_n$ and $E_{n+3}$ cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Ok, It is my mistake that I didn't noticed that $M$ is not abelian.

Comment: You have probably already checked this, but Magma says that for p=3 and n=1, the groups are isomorphic.